# Unable to start a command line with spaces from C#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

The command line I need to execute is
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /Run "C:\unity\unity\MRTK Tutorial\Builds\MRTK Tutorial.sln"`

This works from a windows command line without issues,
I formatted it into a string for visual studio

When running from C# this command never executes and the contents of `result` are `""`

```
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =  new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Program Files(x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Enterprise\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe", " /Run \"C:\\unity\\unity\\MRTK Tutorial\\Builds\\MRTK Tutorial.sln\"");

            // The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
            // This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            // Do not create the black window.
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            // Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
```

Comment: The command and  the arguements are separate properties.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=net-5.0

Comment: `// Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it` is not correct; `proc` does not have an assigned `ProcessStartInfo` nor are you `Start()`ing it.  Try `Process proc = Process.Start(procStartInfo);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code to use c# to execute devenv.exe.

```
        var devEnvPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe";
        string SolutionFile = @"D:\Test\testconsole\testconsole.sln";
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(devEnvPath);
        startInfo.Arguments = "/Run " + SolutionFile;
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Based on my test, the above code will open vs2019 and open the startup project.

Comment: Thanks, Visual Studio is launching, but I am weirdly getting the error from within visual studio that  `The following files do not exist C:\unity\unity\MRTK Tutorial\Builds\MRTK Tutorial.sln` I double checked the path and sln file are both there and load correctly when I run from command line

Comment: @Mich, based on my further test, there is no problem about my code. I can run the vs2019 and open the startup project correctly. Also, I changed to the path in the c disk and d disk. I suggest that you can copy your project to D disk to change to file path to make a test.